# How to read Gradle's registry.bin?

Tags: build, android-studio, build-process, android-gradle-plugin

I was working on Android studio (on the Mac) when I got the following message:

> Error:Could not read cache value from
>   '/Users/Friso/.gradle/daemon/2.2.1/registry.bin'.

I don't know what caused it, since I didn't do anything to the build files.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try deleting the `/Users/Friso/.gradle` directory and rebuild.

Comment: Do you know how it might have become corrupted, so I can avoid that in the future?

Comment: There's nothing specific I know of that I can tell you.

Comment: @Friso1990, It happened to me after downloading new stuff on Android SDK Manager and deleting old one. Maybe that was the reason.

Comment: it also happened when you have a low disk space. In my case, just delete the registry.bin and it will rebuild itself after restart.

Comment: Yes, low disk space was the reason in my case as well. Deleting just ".gradle/daemon/<gradle_version>/registry.bin.lock" file worked for me.

Answer (score 21):

In my case, the registry.bin file was empty. However, there was a lock which seemed to be causing the issue. I deleted the lock file - registry.bin.lock from the /Users/varun/.gradle/daemon/2.8/ directory and it worked.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This was my case and was triggered by exceeded disk-quota. Once the lock file was removed (and after removing old files from my disk), everything went back to normal. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

It also happened in my Linux environment. Deleting .gradle folder and rebuilding the project worked again.

Answer (score 3):

The gradle directory (or one of its caches) is likely corrupted in some way.  The easiest way to proceed is to delete the directory entirely.  Navigate to /Users/Friso and run:

```
sudo rm -r .gradle
sudo rm -r ~/.gradle
```

This recursively removes the directory and all files within it.  The latter is your home gradle cache.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had stopped the grade in between and turned off my laptop.The next time I opened and ran my gradle it gave error of  could not read cache value from registry.bin.
The error was coming in every project of mine.
I did the following:
Go to C:\users\username.gradle\daemon\gradle version and delete registry.bin.lock file.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete registry lock file from c:\users{username}.gradle\demon{version} and then build again